# The meaning of "one would notice no inequality."

Tags: meaning

> Mrs. Brown was never so violent and could not have been so, but if any
>   half-dozen of lady Wentworth's sonnets were to be mixed with the same
>   number of Mrs. Browning's , or with those of any woman who ever wrote
>   in English, **one would notice no inequality.**

What is the meaning of "one would notice no inequality."
Does it mean the equality of their sonnets?

I am glad of some one would kindly teach me,

Answer (score 1):

To *notice* something is to become aware of that thing in some way. e.g. if I notice a plane in the sky, I have probably heard its engine and then looked up and seen it.

The word "*inequality*" is often used nowadays when referring to differences between groups of people, for instance with respect to social status, wealth, and so on.

But that is not how "*inequality*" is used here. The style of the text is clearly much older, and uses a correspondingly older sense of the word.  Here an inequality between two things means they are not equal in quality - that is in value, or standard, or merit.

In this sense, if we notice no inequality between two things, we are  unaware of any difference in quality between them.

So in this text, an inequality refers to the quality of the sonnets - i.e. in their merit or value as poetry. If sonnets from Lady Wentworth and Mrs. Browning were mixed together, we would not be aware of any difference in the quality of the sonnets.  We could not determine who had written each sonnet without further information. In other words, Lady Wentworth and Mrs. Browning are equally good poets.